# Google Play Store Apache Cordova Vulnerabilities says it affects the previous app version that is in the play store

Tags: android-security

As we used Cordova version 4.2.0 we upgraded to Cordova 6.4.0 and upgraded all the plugins related to it and we generated the new alpha build for testing.  We are getting the warning as "Your app is using a version of Apache Cordova containing one or more security vulnerabilities. Affected Apk Version 10601".  Why we are getting this message even after upgrading the versions?